# Unsupervised learning, Python, text clustering

Tags: python, text-mining

I want to do unsupervised learning. As I understand with such learning we don't know the cluseters before, right? I read about k-means alghoritm, followed mainly these two articles:

- https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/applying-machine-learning-to-classify-an-unsupervised-text-document-e7bb6265f52

And maybe this sounds stupid but this is some kind of magic for me, that following the example from towardsdatascience suddenly out of nothing  "Python" knows the clusters.

My problem is to understand how it works from inside. I have around 100 text documents (resumes) and would like to play with this alghoritm - maybe start with 2 clusters - experienced/notExperienced but don't want just to copy the code  from tutorials.

Comment: it always need some function to calculate so called "distance" between items. For points `(x,y)` you can use function which calculate real distance between points. For other items you can calculate other value (ie. time between two eventes, difference in price/weight/speed). This way you can compare elements. In this example it uses TD-TFA to assign values to words and to calculate "distance" between words.

Comment: At start it gets two random words (which will create two clusters at start) and then it compare every word with these words (using values TD-TFA) and add other word to one of these clusters. After spliting all words to two clusters it gets in every cluster word which has middle value in cluster - and it uses these words to create new two clusters and again compare all words with theses words and split to clusters.